# compute knockout variable using external function during mapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a problem with compute variable that should be binded to the "`src`" attribute.

**Here is html:**

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'attachements-template', foreach: attachements }">
    </ul>

    <script type="text/html" id="attachements-template">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: FileName"></span>
            <img class="file-type-icon" data-bind="attr:{src: ImagePath}"/>
        </li>
    </script>
```

**Here is model:**

```
var Attachement = function () {
    var self = this;

    this.Id = ko.observable();
    this.FileName = ko.observable();        
    self.ImagePath = ko.computed(function () {
        return "images/" + getFileType(self.FileName);
    });
};

var AttachementListModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.attachements = ko.observableArray([new Attachement()]);
    ...
};
```

`getFileType` is just some js function that returns some string like "image" or "document":
I believe this is a problem and this give me "Uncaught TypeError: Object function observable() ... "

**Is it possible to compute variable via external function?**

However, I have also a problem without this function.

```
    self.ImagePath = ko.computed(function () {
        return "images/" + self.FileName;
    });
```

Here is how I load data into `attachementListModel.attachements`:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        attachementListModel = new AttachementListModel();
        ko.applyBindings(attachementListModel, document.getElementById("@uniqueAttachementsPanelId"));

        // get all attachements for given business entity data
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/attachement",
            contentType: "text/json",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET",
            data: { businessEntityType: "type", id: 1 },
            success: function (data) {
                attachementListModel.attachements(data);  
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });

    })
```

In this case (without external function) t give error: Unable to parse bindings. ...(anonymous function).

So, I do not know if the problem is with `attachementListModel.attachements(data);` part, where some mapping happends, or with other parts of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to unwrap your `FileName` observable with `self.FileName()` in your `ImagePath` computed:

```
self.ImagePath = ko.computed(function () {
    return "images/" + getFileType(self.FileName());
});
```

However your `fileName` may be `undefinied` because `getFileType` gets called before you setting the `FileName`.

You can make your computed defered so it will only call your `getFileType`when you actually 
use `ImagePath`:

```
self.ImagePath = ko.computed(
    function () { return "images/" + getFileType(self.FileName()); } , 
    self, 
    { deferEvaluation: true }
);
```

And your second problem as that with the `attachementListModel.attachements(data);` there is no mapping happens automatically. You need to this by hand or use the mapping plugin.

To do it by manually you will need something like:

```
success: function (data) {
   ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(item) {
       var attachment = new Attachement();
       attachment.Id(item.Id);
       attachment.FileName(item.FileName);
       attachementListModel.attachements.push(attachment);  
   });
},
```

Comment: It still give me error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to parse bindings. Bindings value: attr:{src: ImagePath} Message: ImagePath is not defined.

Comment: my getfiletyp now is:  function getFileType(fileName) { return "word.gif"; }

Comment: Mybe this is because  attachementListModel.attachements(data);, becaues "data" doesn't contain ImagePath.

Comment: @renathy `attachementListModel.attachements(data);`, does not map your data automatically... I've updated my answer.

Comment: self.FileName() is always undefined in getFileType function. If I remove getFileType function at all (return "images/" + self.FileName(); then the value appears, but if I add a function then it is not passed into function correctly.

Comment: Please post your `getFileType` function! Basacuase something like this should work: `function getFileType(fileName) { return //do something with fileName; }`

Comment: function getFileType(fileName) { console.log(fileName); return "word"; } Console shows fileName = undefined. Now I simply return "word", but I have to use fileName with some jquery functions, but this doens't work because fileName is undefined.

Comment: The fileName is undefinied because it gets called before you setting the FileName. You can make your computed defered with `self.ImagePath = ko.computed(function () {
    return "images/" + getFileType(self.FileName());
}, self, {deferEvaluation: true});` so it will only call your `getFileType` when you actually use `ImagePath`